# Function returning a dataset in R

Tags: r, function, return, dataset

I have written the below function in R to split a data set into Test/Train. I need my code to create 2 datasets called test and train. I am getting the result, however, it is being printed to the console. I need it to be created as a dataset.

```
    splt <- function(x,y){
    intrain <- sort(sample(nrow(x), nrow(x)*y))
    train <- x[intrain,]
    test <- x[-intrain,]
    train <- data.frame(train)
    test <- data.frame(test)
    return(test)
    return(train)
    }
    splt(iris,0.75)
```

I am using the inbuilt 'iris' dataset in R. The aim of the code is to sample 75% of the dataset randomly and store it as 'train' and store the remaining as 'test'. I need the function to create 2 data frames by itself and not just display them in the console. Also, I do not want to explicitly assign it to a variable outside the function to create a dataframe like `train <- splt(iris,0.75)`. I want the function to create data frames by itself. Is there any way to do it..? Is it even possible..?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can only return a single object from a function in R. In your code above, it reaches the line `return(test)`, and returns that `data.frame`. The line `return(train)` is never run.

If you want to return two `data.frames`, you can do this by wrapping them in a `list()`:

```
splt <- function(x,y){
  intrain <- sort(sample(nrow(x), nrow(x)*y))
  obj <- list(
    "train" = x[intrain,]
    "test" = x[-intrain,]
  )
  return(obj)
}

# get the two data frames from the returned list:
split_data <- splt(iris,0.75) 
train <- split_data$train
test <- split_data$test
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Scott. I didn't realize that return(train) didn't run at all. But as I asked, is there not a way that the function creates those dataframes itself ? without we `train <- split_data$train` `test <- split_data$test` doing that explicitly outside the function ?

Comment: You can use `<<-` to assign to a variable outside the function, but this is generally considered bad practice (for example it would overwrite any variables called `test` and `train` already existing in your R session)